# Object use problem?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

When I run the following code, the app just drops out?

thanks...

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface dogViewController : UIViewController {

}

@end

/////////////////////////////////////////

#import "dogViewController.h"
#import "puppy.h"


@implementation dogViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"start");

    puppy *w;
    int r = [w waldo];

    NSLog(@"%d",r);
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end

////////////////////////////////////////

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface puppy : NSObject {

}
-(int) waldo;
@end

///////////////////////////////////////

#import "puppy.h"


@implementation puppy
-(int) waldo{
    return (int)29;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
puppy *w;
```

Doesn't do anything useful, it just declares a puppy variable. You'll have to actually initialize one, for example:

```
puppy *w = [[puppy alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you a referencing w without instantiating it.
To be able to send waldo to w you need to alloc and init it.

```
puppy *w = [[puppy alloc] init];
// now w is created so it you can call methods on it...
int r = [w waldo];
```